# Is every concretizable category equivalent to a subcategory of the category of sets?

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

A category $\mathcal C$ is called *concretizable* if there is a faithful functor $U\colon \mathcal C\to \mathbf{Sets}$.

Of course, each subcategory $\mathcal C$ of the category of sets $\mathbf{Sets}$ is concretizable, since in this case, the embedding $\mathcal C\hookrightarrow\mathbf{Sets}$ is faithful.

But is every concretizable category equivalent (or even isomorphic) to a subcategory of $\mathbf{Sets}$? At least I don't know a counterexample.

Comment: I thought it's $\bf Set$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any concretizable category is isomorphic to a subcategory of $\mathbf{Sets}$.  Given a faithful functor $U:\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Sets}$, define $U':\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Sets}$ by $U'(X)=U(X)\cup\{(X,U(X))\}$ (and on morphisms we use $U$ on the first term of the union and the unique map on the second term).  Then $U'$ is still faithful but is injective on objects (since $(X,U(X))$ is the unique element of $U'(X)$ of maximal rank, so $X$ can be recovered from $U'(X)$).  It follows that the image of $U'$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{Sets}$ (we can't have non-composable morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ that become composable after applying $U'$), and $U'$ gives an isomorphism from $\mathcal{C}$ to this subcategory.