# Are concretizable categories necessarily small?

Tags: category-theory

There is a partial answer here: [Is every concretizable category equivalent to a subcategory of the category of sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317487/is-every-concretizable-category-equivalent-to-a-subcategory-of-the-category-of-s)

If the answer is negative, please provide an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The category $\mathbf {Set}$ is concretizable but not small.