# About isomorphism of each category to a category of ordered semicategories with actions

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I will call an *ordered semicategory with action* (OSA) an ordered semicategory that is also a semicategory with actions acting on ordered elements, where the action preserves the order of both elements and morphisms. I denote the action of a morphism $f$ as $\langle f\rangle$.

I call two morphisms $\mu$ and $\nu$ of OSA isomorphic, when they are isomorphic as morphisms of ordered semicategories, and there is a bijection $f$ mapping ($\langle\nu\rangle=f\circ\langle\mu\rangle\circ f^{-1}$) the action of $\mu$ to the action of $\nu$.

I will call *space-in-general* an endomorphism of an ordered semicategory with action.

Background: On different examples from general topology (metrics, locales/frames and everything in between, such as topological spaces, uniform spaces, etc.) I show that we have interesting representation of these examples as a special cases of space-in-general. There appears a natural question: Is every mathematical structure representable as a space-in-general? (That paragraph is not used in the question, but explains why I am interested in this question.)

As easily follows from [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3317571/4876), every concrete category is isomorphic to a subcategory of the category of ordered semicategory actions (take a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ with identity order).

Is every concrete category isomorphic (by some both category isomorphism and order isomorphism $\tau$) to a subcategory of OSA in such a way that spaces-in-general $a$ and $b$ are isomorphic if and only if $\tau(a)$ is isomorphic as an OSA to $\tau(b)$? If yes, how can this equivalence be strengthened to arbitrary morphisms, not only isomorphic ones?

**Change:** I required $\tau$ to be an order isomorphism.

Comment: @EricWofsey take a look of this question, because it's somehow related to an answer by you.

Comment: We can easily exclude order and ask whether every concrete category is isomorphic by $\tau$ to a subcategory of semicategories with actions, such that $a$ is isomorphic to $b$ iff $\tau a$ is isomorphic to $\tau b$ as semicategories with actions.

Comment: A "philosophical" (heuristic) argument against my conjecture: if every structure is isomorphic to OSA, then structure with added partial order is also isomorphic to it. But partial order is already present in for instance the category of topological spaces. So, we do partial order two times, what makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I a little modified my question to make this answer trivial. (Please check for errors, however.)

The answer is almost trivial:

First remove the order from the question by solving instead: is every concrete category is isomorphic by $\tau$ to a subcategory of semicategories with actions, such that $\tau a$ is isomorphic to $\tau b$ iff $\tau a$ is isomorphic to $\tau b$ as semicategories with actions. (Then we add order to our semicategory by the formula $\tau a\leq\tau b\Leftrightarrow a\leq b$ (what is well-defined because $\tau$ is a bijection).

Now it's trivial: For a concretizable category $C$ take $\tau$ its faithful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$. Then $(\operatorname{Mor}C,\tau)$ is a category with action $\tau$. $\mu$ is isomorphic to $\nu$ in our semicategory when they are isomorphic as morphisms of $C$ and there is a bijection $f$ such that $\langle\nu\rangle=f\circ\langle\mu\rangle\circ f^{-1}$ that is when $\tau\nu=f\circ(\tau\mu)\circ f^{-1}$. Because $\tau$ is an isomorphism, this is equivalent ($\tau^{-1}$ is defined because it's faithful) to $\nu=(\tau^{-1}f)\circ\mu\circ(\tau^{-1}f)^{-1}$ and by faithfulness of $\tau$ we have $\tau^{-1}f$ being isomorphism, so $\mu$ is isomorphic to $\nu$.

Comment: It follows that space-in-general is an endomorphism of an concrete over somehow ordered $\mathbf{Set}$ category. (Check.)

Comment: Another important result is that to each concrete category it corresponds a single (up to isomorphisms) semicategory with action. If it is ordered, it corresponds an ordered semicategory with action, whose morphisms are spaces-in-general, thus having exactly one (up to isomorphism) space-in-general for each algebraic structure! Every structure is space - we can define open and closed element, Hausdorffness, compactness, etc. for every algebraic structure!